# L'Hospital's Rule and indeterminate form $\frac{\infty}{-\infty}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Suppose I have a limit of the form
\begin{align*}
\lim\limits_{x \to -\infty} \frac{x}{e^{x^2}}.
\end{align*}
As $x \to -\infty$, $x \to -\infty$ and $e^{x^2} \to \infty$. Now, if we were subtracting this limit (suppose, for example, we're evaluating some term in the integration by parts formula from $\infty$ to $-\infty$), it doesn't quite matter. We can move constants outside a limit, and can surely move them back in as well. $-x \to \infty$ as $x \to -\infty$, so that is our $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ indeterminate form which allows us to apply L'Hospital's rule. But, what if this weren't the case? Is $\frac{\infty}{-\infty}$ an indeterminate form? I suppose I could multiply the limit by $1 = \frac{-1}{-1}$ and pull one of $-1$'s outside the limit to turn this limit into the form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$, though this feels like cheating. I'm really concerned with whether this is valid.

I'd appreciate any insights on this.

Comment: It is my understanding that L'Hopital applies to the infinite over infinite case without restriction.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, $\frac\infty{-\infty}$ and $\frac{-\infty}\infty$ are indeterminate forms. And you can apply L'Hopital's Rule to $\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac x{e^{x^2}}$. So, compute$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac1{2xe^{x^2}}=0.$$So, $\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac x{e^{x^2}}=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,You can really bring $-1$ outside so that it changes to $\frac\infty{\infty}$ form . It's not 'cheating'